# Can i push html element in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example i have some data need to be push into a variable

```
var WhiteLists = profile.whiteList;
            for(var i=0;i<WhiteLists.length;i++){
              WhiteListRender.push('<div style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="temporayWhiteSingle"><span class="white-url-item" style="margin-bottom:10px;width: 600px;padding:5px;border-radius: 3px;background-color: #ffffff;border: solid 1px #cbcbcb;" ><span class="" >'+WhiteLists[i]+
              '</span><span class="mobileCreatebtn  sa-btn  BackBtn2" style="padding: 5px;border-radius: 5px;border: solid 1px steelblue;position: relative;left: 75px;"><a class="white-url-delete">&nbsp;Remove</a></span></div>');

        }
```

As you see i tried to push the html tag and inline css as well, i thought it's going to return some data with html and css style but it actually read everything as string so my outcome became as the image show below:

[image]
Should i do it in another way?

Comment: Try to render the array element as innerHTML of the element

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: You are adding strings so of course it is an array of strings. If you want it to be DOM elements, you need to append DOM elements. You need to look at createElement or $() with jQuery

Comment: Needs to be in the DOM to be able to see any styling, what is the overall objective for this array?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data in as a string, so it comes out as the same string. If you are using jquery (as your tag suggests) an easy way of creating HTML is with $('stringOfHTML').

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the element first and set it's innerHTML.

```
var WhiteLists = profile.whiteList;
for(var i=0;i<WhiteLists.length;i++){

  var div = document.createElement('DIV'); 
  div.style.margin-bottom = "20px"; 
  div.className = "temporayWhiteSingle"; 

  div.innerHTML = '<span class="white-url-item" style="margin-bottom:10px;width: 600px;padding:5px;border-radius: 3px;background-color: #ffffff;border: solid 1px #cbcbcb;" ><span class="" >'+WhiteLists[i]+
                  '</span><span class="mobileCreatebtn  sa-btn  BackBtn2" style="padding: 5px;border-radius: 5px;border: solid 1px steelblue;position: relative;left: 75px;"><a class="white-url-delete">&nbsp;Remove</a></span>'; 

    WhiteListRender.push(div);

 }
```